# General periodic recurrences

Tags: recurrence-relations

I was blown away when I read in *Concrete Math* that the recurrence
$$Q_0 = \alpha$$
$$Q_1 = \beta$$
$$Q_n = \frac{Q_{n-1} + 1}{Q_{n-2}}$$
is periodic (period 5). Is there a general method to determine if a recurrence is periodic? What are some general classes of periodic recurrences? *Why is $Q_n$ periodic???*

Comment: This sequence belongs to a fairly special class of sequences. It's very surprising that a nonlinear recurrence behaves so nicely and there's some nontrivial math behind this. Look up "Laurent phenomenon" and "cluster algebra" for some more information about it.